# Поисковая система при помощи Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model, django-filter

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задание.

Есть модель Джанго Post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='posts'
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        Group,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        max_length=200,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='posts')
```

А это само задание: "Допишите код view-функции: она должна вывести на главную страницу посты, в которых есть запрошенное ключевое слово. Форма отправляет запрос методом GET.
Запрос сделайте так, чтобы при обращении к свойствам модели author и group не порождались дополнительные запросы к базе."
Код из файла со вьюшкой:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Post, User


def index(request):
    keyword = request.GET.get("q", None)
    if keyword:
        posts = ...
    else:
        posts = None

    return render(request, "index.html", {"posts": posts, "keyword": keyword})
```

В переменной posts нужно написать запрос в БД. Все, на что меня хватило, это: posts = Post.objects.filter(text__contains='keyword '). Но я не понимаю, как дальше построить запрос, чтобы при поиске выводился не только текст поста, но и поля author и group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня вот такой код прошёл:

```
def index(request):
    keyword = request.GET.get("q", None)
    if keyword:
        posts = Post.objects.filter(text__contains=keyword).select_related('author', 'group')
    else:
        posts = None

    return render(request, "index.html", {"posts": posts, "keyword": keyword})
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно, чтобы поиск введенного слова велся еще и по авторам, то Вам следует использовать Q в фильтрации, получиться что то вроде такого:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    Q(text__icontains=keyword) | 
    Q(author__fio__icontains=keyword) |
    Q(group__name__icontains=keyword)
)
```

только нужно вместо `fio` подставить поле из модели авторов, а вместо `name` название группы.

Подробней о Q - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects

Comment: Здравствуйте!Это не правильно.пожалуйста поправите ваш код.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, копировал и забыл удалить text__

Comment: я исправил ,вы раньше написали     Q(text__author__fio__icontains=keyword) |
    Q(text__group__name__icontains=keyword) и это неправильно должен быть     Q(author__fio__icontains=keyword) |
    Q(group__name__icontains=keyword).